# How to consider the value of a vector is in specific range of values of another matrix in matlab?

Tags: matlab, vector, range

I have a vector A with size of 54000 x 2. Each row includes range of accepted min and accepted max of values for that row. For example:

```
A=[0.5 1.5 ; 1 2.5; -0.5 1.5]
```

From the other side, I have vector C with size of 300000 x 1. Now I want to find that each value of vector C can be placed in which rows of Matrix A. for example:

```
C= [1.2; -0.3; 2.4 ]
```

Now, I need to know that each value of vector C can be located in which rows of A. So the result of indices could be like this :

```
   c_indx(1,1)= [1,1,1]
   c_indx(2,1)= [0,0,1]
   c_indx(3,1)= [0,1,0]
```

THX for your help

Comment: So, you would end up with `54000 x 300000` sized logical array? [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)?

Comment: yes. Because I need to find the corresponding indices between Vector C and matrix A  that's why I used logical array. Is there better solution ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bit more intuitive to me would be:

```
c_indx = bsxfun(@le,A(:,1).',C) & bsxfun(@ge,A(:,2).',C);
```

However, by making use of row-operations, it should be computationally faster like this:

```
c_indx = cell2mat(arrayfun(@(x)(A(:,1)<=x & A(:,2)>=x).',C,'UniformOutput',false))
```

Comment: THX for solution. it works fine but it is super slow! Since the combination of those size means 1.7 B process should be done! is there any faster code?

Answer (score 1):

Using [`bsxfun`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html)

```
out = all(cat(3,bsxfun(@le,C(:),A(:,2).'),bsxfun(@ge,C(:),A(:,1).')),3);
```

**Sample run:**

```
A = [0.5 1.5 ; 1 2.5; -0.5 1.5];
C= [1.2; -0.3; 2.4];

>> out

out =

 1     1     1
 0     0     1
 0     1     0
```

---

```
A=[0.5,  1.5 ;  1,   2.5; -0.5,  1.5];

C= [1.2; -0.3;  2.4;  1.7;  0.3;  -0.6;  1.1];

>> out

out =

 1     1     1
 0     0     1
 0     1     0
 0     1     0
 0     0     1
 0     0     0
 1     1     1
```